# Why content is not same after parsing with Jsoup

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse [this](http://hindi-stories.kratav.com/content/social_aalha.html) url using JSOUP. I am getting parsed doc something like unicode format not the actual data while I am parsing [this](http://www.bharatdarshan.co.nz/magazine/literature/427/patni-jainendra.html) url gives me proper hindi text as desired. I am using below code to parse URl. BTW url is hosted on my site. Is there any problem with text file on server? I am not able to figure this out.

```
    Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect(
                    "hindi-stories.kratav.com/content/social_aalha.html")
            .userAgent("Mozilla").timeout(15 * 1000).get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you check the source code of the first URL, there is no encoding specified. whereas the second has a meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Try to parse the first URL using a method specifying the charset, i.e:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-16", url);
```

Comment: I tried and getting same result.

Comment: Insteed of ISO-8859-1 UTF-16 worked thanks Man

Comment: great. I updating the answer accordingly.